# Inserting data into Oracle by Stored Procedure with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert data into Oracle database with OracleDataAdapter, I am using stored procedure. I am not getting any error, data is also not committing into DB.

```
public DeviceType AddDeviceType(DeviceType deviceType)
        {
            DeviceType objDeviceType = new DeviceType();
            using (cmd = new OracleCommand("SP_DMS_DEVICE_TYPE_INSERT", con))
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add("p_typename", OracleType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_typename", deviceType.DeviceTypeName).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_createdby", deviceType.CreatedBy).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_createdon", deviceType.CreatedOn).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_updatedby", deviceType.UpdatedBy).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_updatedon", deviceType.UpdatedOn).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                    con.Open();
                    adap = new OracleDataAdapter();
                    adap.InsertCommand = cmd;                    
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                return objDeviceType;
            }
        }
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEV_INV.SP_DMS_DEVICE_TYPE_INSERT
(
   //--p_id IN DMS_DEVICE_TYPE.ID%TYPE,
   p_typename IN DMS_DEVICE_TYPE.DEVICE_TYPE_NAME%Type,
   p_createdby IN DMS_DEVICE_TYPE.CREATED_BY%Type,
   p_createdon IN DMS_DEVICE_TYPE.CREATED_ON%TYPE,
   p_updatedby IN DMS_DEVICE_TYPE.UPDATED_BY%Type,
   p_updatedon IN DMS_DEVICE_TYPE.UPDATED_ON%Type
)
AS

   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO DMS_DEVICE_TYPE ("ID","DEVICE_TYPE_NAME","CREATED_BY","CREATED_ON","UPDATED_BY","UPDATED_ON")
     VALUES (DMS_DEVICE_TYPE_S.NextVal, p_typename, p_createdby, p_createdon, p_updatedby, p_updatedon);
     COMMIT;
   END SP_DMS_DEVICE_TYPE_INSERT;
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the exception you catch (if there is one) outside of closing the connection, and the `using` statement will do that for you when the block is exited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` method to execute stored procedure. So replace this:

```
con.Open();
adap = new OracleDataAdapter();
adap.InsertCommand = cmd;
```

With this

```
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You could achieve what you wanted with `InsertCommand` too. You needed to call `adap.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` method. But obviously it is bulky. And when you are calling a single procedure there is no need to create an adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `OracleDataAdapter` in your case. All you have to do is to call the execute method.

```
// other codes here

con.Open();
int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: then what OracleDataAdapter .InserCommad do ?

Comment: `OracleDataAdapter` is another class specifically used to fill dataset. `InsertCommand` property is used to set sql statement or stored procedure called during inserting of new record.